# My bootstrap 5 carousel buttons are not working

Tags: bootstrap-5

I can't seem to figure out why the buttons don't work when clicked on. Both carousel items are there (confirmed by changing which is active).
I have looked on the getbootstrap website and followed the code how it explains but there is no change.
Could it be that I'm missing a link in the head that I could not find / am unaware of?

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>TinDog</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles2.css">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vSIIfh2YWi9wW0r9iZe7RJPrKwp6bG+s9QZMoITbCckVJqGCCRhc+ccxNcdpHuYu" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<!-- Testimonial Section -->
  <section id="testimonials">

    <div id="testimonials" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-keyboard="true">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-img" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-image">
          <em class="pebbles">Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2>My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-img" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-img">
          <em class="beverly">Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>
      </div>

<!-- Carousel Buttons -->
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonials"  data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonials"  data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>

    </div>

  </section>
```

Comment: When I run the code snippet, I don't see any buttons rendered. I do see the button tags in your html, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `id="testimonials` from this line

```
 <section id="testimonials">
```

an ID should only be used once,  and in this case the id `testimonials` is on the line that it needs to be (the buttons use this as their target `data-bs-target="#testimonials"`)

```
<div id="testimonials" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-keyboard="true">
```

I am noticing that the version number of your bootstrap CSS and JS do not match.  I would swap these CDNs with the ones provided on the [bootstrap 5 page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) this helped give the desired result.

CSS - `5.0.0-beta2`

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

JS - `5.0.0-alpha2`

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<!-- A blank template with twitter bootsrap and dependencies added as external resources, to play around. Feel free to fork this and use. -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TinDog</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles2.css">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vSIIfh2YWi9wW0r9iZe7RJPrKwp6bG+s9QZMoITbCckVJqGCCRhc+ccxNcdpHuYu" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <!-- Testimonial Section -->
  <section >

    <div id="testimonials" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-keyboard="true">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="dog-image">
          <em class="pebbles">Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2>My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" alt="lady-img">
          <em class="beverly">Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Carousel Buttons -->
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonials" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonials" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>

    </div>

  </section>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly now. The reason why I had the different CDNs was because the ones I got from getbootstrap were messing up an earlier part of my code, the ones you provided work perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: @Liam, glad it worked!  Glad this CDN combo is doing well.  If my answer helped, please mark it as the best answer, that will help me out.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Change the buttons to anchors and use href. This is from bootstrap.

```html
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP asked for Bootstrap 5 and this is from Bootstrap 4